# accessing data from concurrentHashMap while it gets updated in background android

Tags: android, hashmap, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I have a static concurrentHashMap object which is been updated in background. While it is getting updated, I want to access the values from it in another thread. I am using concurrentHashMap which I understand from the documentation and thinks that it would suit this scenrio

Here is what I am doing

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<property>> entry : alldata.entrySet())
        {
            udata.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<property>(entry.getValue()));
        }
```

in above code I am updating udata on getting data from server but in background.

While in another thread I am accessing some info out of it  ..

```
  for (String s: sTypes) 
        {
                    if(jprocess.udata != null)
                        {
                            if (jprocess.udata.get(s) != null)
                                {
                                    if (jprocess.udata.get(s).size() > 0) {
                                        if (xcor < jprocess.udata.get(s).size())
                                            if (xcor != -1) {
                                                allData.add(jprocess.udata.get(s).get(xcor));
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                }
```

but when I try to access any indexfrom it I can not access anything I hope it is clear what I want..

I already tried ConcurrentHashMap which should work for this situation but may be I did not understand it well..

Comment: which index do you mean?

Comment: any index from hashmap respective to key ....

Comment: first, call it _value_ in order to follow common language, second, are you sure you start accessing data _after_ the map becomes populated?

Comment: that is my point, the map is getting populated contineously in background....so I want to access existing value from it while it is getting appended ...with new data ..

Comment: I believe you need to take a look at `CountDownLatch()` and other classes from java.util.concurrency package.

Comment: no It is not empty as I am doing deep copying using this  new ArrayList<property>(entry.getValue()) where entry.getValue() has data...

Comment: @user3290805 You have 5 nested `if` statements, please tell use where exactly the problem is. `ConcurrentHashMap` should just work, so probably you are passing the wrong keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ConcurrentHashMap, then there is not point it will not work. I strongly doubt that you are trying to access wrong index or you do not have synchronization between inserting and accessing the particular index.

For that just check the size of udata and value of xcor in your code and in each if condition.

In addition, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) carefully and for sure you will be convinced that ConcurrentHashMap is right solution for your issue.